# How to get rid of shadow in Chrome when scrolling

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

Chrome Version: 92.0.4515.10
Windows 10

Recently, Chrome has started having an annoying shadow (I don't know what else to call it) when using the scrollbar or a pen tablet to scroll. How do I get rid of that?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: A screenshot will help.

Comment: Impossible for me to get one. It only appears while in the process of scrolling. I tried PrtSc while scrollingm, but Windows waits until the scroll is done before it allows me to clip the screen.

Comment: Use your smartphone to take a photo while scrolling.